# Java. Port-ing an ArrayList to other classes

Tags: java, object, file-io, arraylist, java.util.scanner

here i have a CreateEmployee class and i would like to use this employeeList inside my Company class. How do i go about doing that?

What i have tried was to put do the create employee class codes inside the company class.
That would work, however, i would like to understand more on how to do it in a external class and port it into company class, as it will help in cases where other classes will require the ArrayList

```
public class CreateEmployee {

    private ArrayList<Employee> employeeList;
    Scanner fileScanner;

    String name;
    String pw;
    String [] dataArray;
    String data;
    int salary;

    public CreateEmployee(){

        try
        {
            fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("employee.dat")); 
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("FileNotFoundException caught");
        }

        employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        while(fileScanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            //reset the array for every new line
            dataArray = new String [10];

            //take the file line and split into 3 different parts
            data = fileScanner.nextLine();
            dataArray = data.split("\\|");

            //assign the 3 different parts to the variables.
            name = dataArray[0];
            pw = dataArray[1]; // this is a error. only after first run.
            salary = Integer.parseInt(dataArray[2]);

            //create a player object, add to playerList
            Employee employee = new Employee(name, pw, salary);
            employeeList.add(employee);
        }
    }


    public ArrayList getEmployeeList(){
        return employeeList;
    }

    public void funcA(){
         //sample method to be executed at Company class
    }

}


public class Company{
         public Company{
             //i would like to call the CreateEmployee constructor here.
             // how should i go about it?
         }

         public static void main(String[] args){
              new Company().run();
         }

         public void run(){
             //i would like to call a function of CreateEmployee class here.
             // how should i go about it?
         {

}
```

Comment: Why are you doing everything in the `CreateEmployee` constructor?  `new CreateEmployee();`?

Answer (score 0):

You would create a new instance of the CreateEmployee class:

```
CreateEmployee employees = new CreateEmployee();
```

You would then just call getEmployeeList and store the result.
ie:

```
ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = employees.getEmployeeList();
```